# how to override the `class-name > *:last-child` in css globally

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-specificity

If I want to override a css class where specificity is not working, I use the following format which works well.

```
div[class="class-name"] {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

But how to override the class in the form `bx--modal-content > *:last-child` ?
The following is not working.

```
div[class="bx--modal-content > *:last-child"] {
        padding-bottom: 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide an [MCVE] that actually demonstrates the problem. CSS issues are easier to debug with corresponding HTML . Specificity works you just need to come up with a more specific rule. `!important` is an **absolute** last resort. Use the developer tools in the browser of your choice to inspect the elements that are causing you issues. This is the best way to overcome specificity problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The selector should be

```
div[class="bx--modal-content"] > *:last-child {
  padding-bottom: 0;
]
```

The `> *:last-child` isn't part of the class, so it shouldn't be inside the `[ ... ]` brackets.

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is invalid

```
div[class="bx--modal-content > *:last-child"] {
        padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

You don't have a class attribute that is "bx--modal-content > *:last-child"

What you actually want is

```
div[class="bx--modal-content"] > *:last-child] {
        padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

This will select that last child element contained within a `div` with a class attribute *exactly* equal to `bx--modal-content`. It will **not** match something like `<div class="bx--modal-content small">`

Comment: For my knowledge :
How to match the <div class="bx--modal-content small"> ?
Should we use all the classes like below ?

div[class="bx--modal-content small"]

Comment: That would work but you are better off using a [class selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Class_selectors). E.g `div.bx--modal-content` will match all divs with class `bx--modal-content`, regardless of it's position in the class list. If you want to select any div with both those classes you would use `div.bx--modal-content.small`

Answer (score 0):

You could use, as an exception, an `!important` suffix in your first css, so that specificity rules are ignored. Place it juste before the trailing `;`

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
div[class="bx--modal-content > *:last-child"] {
        padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    }
```

or

```
:host /deep/ --> before the class if you want override plugins
```